# Python Word Prob Issue

Tags: python

Here's the word problem: It takes exactly 2 minutes and 7 seconds to produce an item. Unfortunately, after 143 items are produced, the fabricator must cool off for 5 minutes and 13 seconds before it can continue. Write a program that will calculate the amount of time required to manufacture a given number of items.

The test number is 1340 items.

```
numItems = 1340
produceitem = 2 * 60 + 7  #2 minutes and 7 seconds
cooldown = 5 * 60 + 13 #5 minutes and 13 seconds
items_before_delay = 143
productiontime = 0

if numItems <= 143:
    productiontime = produceitem * numItems
if numItems > 143:
    productiontime = (produceitems * numItems) - (numItems / items_before_delay * cooldown) 
print str(productiontime) + "seconds"
```

The output for the test number is supposed to be 172997 seconds but my program outputs it as 167363 seconds.

Can anyone let me know what I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're subtracting the cooldown time, instead of adding it. That's it.

So, change this:

```
productiontime = (produceitems * numItems) - (numItems / items_before_delay * cooldown)
```

… to this:

```
productiontime = (produceitems * numItems) + (numItems / items_before_delay * cooldown)
```

However, while we're here:

- You defined `produceitem`, but used `produceitems`. If this worked at all, it's probably because you got lucky in the interactive interpreter, having already defined `produceitems` as well.
- If you're going to define a constant `items_before_delay`, don't use the number 143 directly, use `items_before_delay`.
- Don't do `if a <= b:` then `if a > b:`; just change the second one to `else:`.
- In fact, you don't need the `if` at all. If `numItems <= 143`, `(numitems / items_before_delay * cooldown)` will be 0, so the second version will still give the right answer.
- Unless you're dealing with pretty old versions of Python, it's generally better to explicitly use `//` for truncating integer division than `/`. That means your code still works in Python 3.x, or if someone does a `__future__` statement, etc.—and, more importantly, it means humans can read and understand your code without having to guess whether it was for 2.x or 3.x.
- Use a consistent style for your names. `items_before_delay` follows PEP8 recommendations, but `numItems` does not.
- There's no need to "declare" a variable like `productiontime` before setting it.
- Concatenating two strings doesn't give you a space in between, and you probably didn't want `172997seconds` without a space.
- Try to avoid writing lines too long to fit in 80 columns. Even if you think nobody cares about old-fashioned text editors, it's still a problem with new-fangled web interfaces like StackOverflow. (Nobody likes unnecessary horizontal scrollbars.)

So:

```
num_items = 1340
produce_item = 2 * 60 + 7  #2 minutes and 7 seconds
cooldown = 5 * 60 + 13 #5 minutes and 13 seconds
items_before_delay = 143

total_cooldown = num_items // items_before_delay * cooldown
production_time = (produce_item * num_items) + total_cooldown
print '{} seconds'.format(production_time)
```

Comment: thx so much! will definitely follow ur advice! 1340 was just a test number. i'm gonna change it to raw input :) @abarnert

Comment: @user2006236: Yeah, I figured it was either going to be `int(raw_input())` or `int(sys.argv[1])` in your real program.